# My multi select is not working, and I can't save data into database

Tags: reactjs, database, frontend, save, multi-select

I tried to make a function that add list of country. But it's not working at the last input (Những ngôn ngữ dịch. I can't save it into database to. What should I do?

I tried to add as much as possible country on the last input. But it didn't show. Here are my code:

```
import '../../css/style.css';
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState, useSelector } from "react";
import { ajaxCallGetUrlDemo, ajaxCallPost } from "../libs/base";
import Select from 'react-select'
import { Const_Libs } from "../libs/Const_Libs";


const ModalAddNgonNgu = (props) => {
    const { handleGetLanguage } = props;
    const [ngonNgu, setNgonNgu] = useState({
        language_name: '',
        main_lang: '',
        title_lang: '',
        describe_lang: '',
        author_lang: '',
        rate_lang: '',
        reviews_lang: '',
        // translate_list: []
        translate_list: []
    });

    function SelectMainLanguage() {
        const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
        const options = [
            { value: 'Vietnamese', label: 'Vietnamese' },
            { value: 'English', label: 'English' },
            { value: 'Chinese', label: 'Chinese' },
            { value: 'Japanese', label: 'Japanese' },
            { value: 'German', label: 'German' },
        ];

        const handleChangeOption = () => {
            return setSelectedOption;
        }
        useEffect(() => {
            if (selectedOption.value) {
                console.log(selectedOption)
                setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, main_lang: selectedOption.value })
            }
        }, [selectedOption])
        // {console.log(selectedOption)}
        return (
            <Select className={`col-12 o-languages`}
                value={ngonNgu.main_lang ? { value: ngonNgu.main_lang, label: ngonNgu.main_lang } : { value: "Chọn ngôn ngữ chính", label: "Chọn ngôn ngữ chính" }}
                onChange={handleChangeOption()}
                options={options} />
        )
    }
    function SelectTransLanguage() {
        const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
        const options = [
            { value: "AF", label: "Afghanistan" },
            { value: "AL", label: "Albania" },
            { value: "DZ", label: "Algeria" },
            { value: "AS", label: "American Samoa" },
            { value: "AD", label: "Andorra" },
            { value: "AO", label: "Angola" },
            { value: "AI", label: "Anguilla" },
            { value: "AQ", label: "Antarctica" },
            { value: "AG", label: "Antigua And Barbuda" },
            { value: "AR", label: "Argentina" },
            { value: "AM", label: "Armenia" },
            { value: "AW", label: "Aruba" },
            { value: "AU", label: "Australia" },
            { value: "AT", label: "Austria" },
            { value: "AZ", label: "Azerbaijan" },
            { value: "BS", label: "Bahamas The" },
            { value: "BH", label: "Bahrain" },
            { value: "BD", label: "Bangladesh" },
            { value: "BB", label: "Barbados" },
            { value: "BY", label: "Belarus" },
            { value: "BE", label: "Belgium" },
            { value: "BZ", label: "Belize" },
            { value: "BJ", label: "Benin" },
            { value: "BM", label: "Bermuda" },
            { value: "BT", label: "Bhutan" },
            { value: "BO", label: "Bolivia" },
            { value: "BA", label: "Bosnia and Herzegovina" },
            { value: "BW", label: "Botswana" },
            { value: "BV", label: "Bouvet Island" },
            { value: "BR", label: "Brazil" },
            { value: "IO", label: "British Indian Ocean Territory" },
            { value: "BN", label: "Brunei" },
            { value: "BG", label: "Bulgaria" },
            { value: "BF", label: "Burkina Faso" },
            { value: "BI", label: "Burundi" },
            { value: "KH", label: "Cambodia" },
            { value: "CM", label: "Cameroon" },
            { value: "CA", label: "Canada" },
            { value: "CV", label: "Cape Verde" },
            { value: "KY", label: "Cayman Islands" },
            { value: "CF", label: "Central African Republic" },
            { value: "TD", label: "Chad" },
            { value: "CL", label: "Chile" },
            { value: "CN", label: "China" },
            { value: "CX", label: "Christmas Island" },
            { value: "CC", label: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" },
            { value: "CO", label: "Colombia" },
            { value: "KM", label: "Comoros" },
            { value: "CG", label: "Congo" },
            { value: "CD", label: "Congo The Democratic Republic Of The" },
            { value: "CK", label: "Cook Islands" },
            { value: "CR", label: "Costa Rica" },
            { value: "CI", label: "Cote D'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)" },
            { value: "HR", label: "Croatia (Hrvatska)" },
            { value: "CU", label: "Cuba" },
            { value: "CY", label: "Cyprus" },
            { value: "CZ", label: "Czech Republic" },
            { value: "DK", label: "Denmark" },
            { value: "DJ", label: "Djibouti" },
            { value: "DM", label: "Dominica" },
            { value: "DO", label: "Dominican Republic" },
            { value: "TP", label: "East Timor" },
            { value: "EC", label: "Ecuador" },
            { value: "EG", label: "Egypt" },
            { value: "SV", label: "El Salvador" },
            { value: "GQ", label: "Equatorial Guinea" },
            { value: "ER", label: "Eritrea" },
            { value: "EE", label: "Estonia" },
            { value: "ET", label: "Ethiopia" },
            { value: "XA", label: "External Territories of Australia" },
            { value: "FK", label: "Falkland Islands" },
            { value: "FO", label: "Faroe Islands" },
            { value: "FJ", label: "Fiji Islands" },
            { value: "FI", label: "Finland" },
            { value: "FR", label: "France" },
            { value: "GF", label: "French Guiana" },
            { value: "PF", label: "French Polynesia" },
            { value: "TF", label: "French Southern Territories" },
            { value: "GA", label: "Gabon" },
            { value: "GM", label: "Gambia The" },
            { value: "GE", label: "Georgia" },
            { value: "DE", label: "Germany" },
            { value: "GH", label: "Ghana" },
            { value: "GI", label: "Gibraltar" },
            { value: "GR", label: "Greece" },
            { value: "GL", label: "Greenland" },
            { value: "GD", label: "Grenada" },
            { value: "GP", label: "Guadeloupe" },
            { value: "GU", label: "Guam" },
            { value: "GT", label: "Guatemala" },
            { value: "XU", label: "Guernsey and Alderney" },
            { value: "GN", label: "Guinea" },
            { value: "GW", label: "Guinea-Bissau" },
            { value: "GY", label: "Guyana" },
            { value: "HT", label: "Haiti" },
            { value: "HM", label: "Heard and McDonald Islands" },
            { value: "HN", label: "Honduras" },
            { value: "HK", label: "Hong Kong S.A.R." },
            { value: "HU", label: "Hungary" },
            { value: "IS", label: "Iceland" },
            { value: "IN", label: "India" },
            { value: "ID", label: "Indonesia" },
            { value: "IR", label: "Iran" },
            { value: "IQ", label: "Iraq" },
            { value: "IE", label: "Ireland" },
            { value: "IL", label: "Israel" },
            { value: "IT", label: "Italy" },
            { value: "JM", label: "Jamaica" },
            { value: "JP", label: "Japan" },
            { value: "XJ", label: "Jersey" },
            { value: "JO", label: "Jordan" },
            { value: "KZ", label: "Kazakhstan" },
            { value: "KE", label: "Kenya" },
            { value: "KI", label: "Kiribati" },
            { value: "KP", label: "Korea North" },
            { value: "KR", label: "Korea South" },
            { value: "KW", label: "Kuwait" },
            { value: "KG", label: "Kyrgyzstan" },
            { value: "LA", label: "Laos" },
            { value: "LV", label: "Latvia" },
            { value: "LB", label: "Lebanon" },
            { value: "LS", label: "Lesotho" },
            { value: "LR", label: "Liberia" },
            { value: "LY", label: "Libya" },
            { value: "LI", label: "Liechtenstein" },
            { value: "LT", label: "Lithuania" },
            { value: "LU", label: "Luxembourg" },
            { value: "MO", label: "Macau S.A.R." },
            { value: "MK", label: "Macedonia" },
            { value: "MG", label: "Madagascar" },
            { value: "MW", label: "Malawi" },
            { value: "MY", label: "Malaysia" },
            { value: "MV", label: "Maldives" },
            { value: "ML", label: "Mali" },
            { value: "MT", label: "Malta" },
            { value: "XM", label: "Man (Isle of)" },
            { value: "MH", label: "Marshall Islands" },
            { value: "MQ", label: "Martinique" },
            { value: "MR", label: "Mauritania" },
            { value: "MU", label: "Mauritius" },
            { value: "YT", label: "Mayotte" },
            { value: "MX", label: "Mexico" },
            { value: "FM", label: "Micronesia" },
            { value: "MD", label: "Moldova" },
            { value: "MC", label: "Monaco" },
            { value: "MN", label: "Mongolia" },
            { value: "MS", label: "Montserrat" },
            { value: "MA", label: "Morocco" },
            { value: "MZ", label: "Mozambique" },
            { value: "MM", label: "Myanmar" },
            { value: "NA", label: "Namibia" },
            { value: "NR", label: "Nauru" },
            { value: "NP", label: "Nepal" },
            { value: "AN", label: "Netherlands Antilles" },
            { value: "NL", label: "Netherlands The" },
            { value: "NC", label: "New Caledonia" },
            { value: "NZ", label: "New Zealand" },
            { value: "NI", label: "Nicaragua" },
            { value: "NE", label: "Niger" },
            { value: "NG", label: "Nigeria" },
            { value: "NU", label: "Niue" },
            { value: "NF", label: "Norfolk Island" },
            { value: "MP", label: "Northern Mariana Islands" },
            { value: "NO", label: "Norway" },
            { value: "OM", label: "Oman" },
            { value: "PK", label: "Pakistan" },
            { value: "PW", label: "Palau" },
            { value: "PS", label: "Palestinian Territory Occupied" },
            { value: "PA", label: "Panama" },
            { value: "PG", label: "Papua new Guinea" },
            { value: "PY", label: "Paraguay" },
            { value: "PE", label: "Peru" },
            { value: "PH", label: "Philippines" },
            { value: "PN", label: "Pitcairn Island" },
            { value: "PL", label: "Poland" },
            { value: "PT", label: "Portugal" },
            { value: "PR", label: "Puerto Rico" },
            { value: "QA", label: "Qatar" },
            { value: "RE", label: "Reunion" },
            { value: "RO", label: "Romania" },
            { value: "RU", label: "Russia" },
            { value: "RW", label: "Rwanda" },
            { value: "SH", label: "Saint Helena" },
            { value: "KN", label: "Saint Kitts And Nevis" },
            { value: "LC", label: "Saint Lucia" },
            { value: "PM", label: "Saint Pierre and Miquelon" },
            { value: "VC", label: "Saint Vincent And The Grenadines" },
            { value: "WS", label: "Samoa" },
            { value: "SM", label: "San Marino" },
            { value: "ST", label: "Sao Tome and Principe" },
            { value: "SA", label: "Saudi Arabia" },
            { value: "SN", label: "Senegal" },
            { value: "RS", label: "Serbia" },
            { value: "SC", label: "Seychelles" },
            { value: "SL", label: "Sierra Leone" },
            { value: "SG", label: "Singapore" },
            { value: "SK", label: "Slovakia" },
            { value: "SI", label: "Slovenia" },
            { value: "XG", label: "Smaller Territories of the UK" },
            { value: "SB", label: "Solomon Islands" },
            { value: "SO", label: "Somalia" },
            { value: "ZA", label: "South Africa" },
            { value: "GS", label: "South Georgia" },
            { value: "SS", label: "South Sudan" },
            { value: "ES", label: "Spain" },
            { value: "LK", label: "Sri Lanka" },
            { value: "SD", label: "Sudan" },
            { value: "SR", label: "Suriname" },
            { value: "SJ", label: "Svalbard And Jan Mayen Islands" },
            { value: "SZ", label: "Swaziland" },
            { value: "SE", label: "Sweden" },
            { value: "CH", label: "Switzerland" },
            { value: "SY", label: "Syria" },
            { value: "TW", label: "Taiwan" },
            { value: "TJ", label: "Tajikistan" },
            { value: "TZ", label: "Tanzania" },
            { value: "TH", label: "Thailand" },
            { value: "TG", label: "Togo" },
            { value: "TK", label: "Tokelau" },
            { value: "TO", label: "Tonga" },
            { value: "TT", label: "Trinidad And Tobago" },
            { value: "TN", label: "Tunisia" },
            { value: "TR", label: "Turkey" },
            { value: "TM", label: "Turkmenistan" },
            { value: "TC", label: "Turks And Caicos Islands" },
            { value: "TV", label: "Tuvalu" },
            { value: "UG", label: "Uganda" },
            { value: "UA", label: "Ukraine" },
            { value: "AE", label: "United Arab Emirates" },
            { value: "GB", label: "United Kingdom" },
            { value: "US", label: "United States" },
            { value: "UM", label: "United States Minor Outlying Islands" },
            { value: "UY", label: "Uruguay" },
            { value: "UZ", label: "Uzbekistan" },
            { value: "VU", label: "Vanuatu" },
            { value: "VA", label: "Vatican City State (Holy See)" },
            { value: "VE", label: "Venezuela" },
            { value: "VN", label: "Vietnam" },
            { value: "VG", label: "Virgin Islands (British)" },
            { value: "VI", label: "Virgin Islands (US)" },
            { value: "WF", label: "Wallis And Futuna Islands" },
            { value: "EH", label: "Western Sahara" },
            { value: "YE", label: "Yemen" },
            { value: "YU", label: "Yugoslavia" },
            { value: "ZM", label: "Zambia" },
            { value: "ZW", label: "Zimbabwe" }
        ];
        const handleChangeOption = () => {
            return setSelectedOption;
        }
        useEffect(() => {
            if (selectedOption.value) {
                console.log(selectedOption)
                setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, translate_list: selectedOption.value })
            }
        }, [selectedOption])

        {console.log(selectedOption)}
        return (
            <Select className={`col-12 o-languages`}
                isMulti
                value={ngonNgu.translate_list ? { value: ngonNgu.translate_list, label: ngonNgu.translate_list } : { value: "Chọn những ngôn ngữ dịch", label: "Chọn những ngôn ngữ dịch" }}
                onChange={handleChangeOption()}
                options={options} />
        )
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        let arr = [{
            nameLanguage: ngonNgu.language_name,
            mainLanguage: ngonNgu.main_lang,
            titleLanguage: ngonNgu.title_lang,
            descriptionLanguage: ngonNgu.describe_lang,
            authorLanguage: ngonNgu.author_lang,
            rateLanguage: ngonNgu.rate_lang,
            reviewsLanguage: ngonNgu.reviews_lang,
            transLanguage: ngonNgu.translate_list
        }]

        ajaxCallPost(`save-lang`, arr).then(rs => {
            resetData()
            handleGetLanguage();
            Const_Libs.TOAST.success("Thêm thành công")
        })
    }

    const resetData = () => {
        setNgonNgu({
            language_name: '',
            main_lang: '',
            title_lang: '',
            describe_lang: '',
            author_lang: '',
            rate_lang: '',
            reviews_lang: '',
            translate_list: []
        })
    }


    return (
        <>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalAddNgonNgu" style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}>
                Thêm
            </button>
            <div>
                <div className="modal fade" id="myModalAddNgonNgu">
                    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style={{ minWidth: '700px' }}>
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <h4 className="modal-title">Thêm ngôn ngữ</h4>
                                <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <form>
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tên ngôn ngữ</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập tên ngôn ngữ...."
                                                value={ngonNgu.language_name}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, language_name: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tiêu đề</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập tiêu đề...."
                                                value={ngonNgu.title_lang}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, title_lang: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Mô tả</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập mô tả...."
                                                value={ngonNgu.describe_lang}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, describe_lang: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Tác giả</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập tác giả (VD: Author)"
                                                value={ngonNgu.author_lang}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, author_lang: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Đánh giá</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập đánh giá (VD: Rate)"
                                                value={ngonNgu.rate_lang}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, rate_lang: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Lượt đánh giá</label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                className="form-control" id="name-campaign"
                                                placeholder="Nhập lượt đánh giá (VD: reviews)"
                                                value={ngonNgu.reviews_lang}
                                                onChange={(e) => setNgonNgu({ ...ngonNgu, reviews_lang: e.target.value })}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Ngôn ngữ chính</label>
                                            <SelectMainLanguage />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="row-2">
                                            <label htmlFor="name-campaign" className="form-label fs-6 fw-bolder">Những ngôn ngữ dịch</label>
                                            <SelectTransLanguage />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default ModalAddNgonNgu;
```

The backend is OK, so the problem is this thing. Can you show me the mistake? Thank you

Comment: one of the problme is with multi select SelectTransLanguage, needs to be an array of options ngonNgu.translate_list?.length ? ngonNgu.translate_list : [...], here ngonNgu.translate_lis needs to be array of [{value, label}]
there are more issues as pointed out in the answer, hope you find a soluion

Answer (score -1):

You should never define a component inside another component.

Move both `SelectMainLanguage` and `SelectTransLanguage` out of `ModalAddNgonNgu`.

Then connect these two components and `ModalAddNgonNgu` with props.

Like this:

```
 const ModalAddNgonNgu = (props) => {

    const { handleGetLanguage } = props; ....

    ... rest of the component

    } // end of ModalAddNgonNgu definition

function SelectTransLanguage({setNgonNgu}) { // setNgonNgu comes from ModalAddNgonNgu

    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({}) ....

    }
```

Comment: I tried. But it's still not work. I think the useEffect() in SelectTransLanguage have problems. Otherwise, when I comment "isMulti", I can add into database. So what should I change to save multi option?